# Is saying 'which team's game is it/today' correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-construction

Let's say my friend is watching a game of soccer or something else and I want to know what the teams are. Can I say

> **Which team's game** is it/are you watching?

Is this construction correct? It sounds a little odd to me. What would be a correct construct in the given context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to have two parts; I'll try to answer appropriately.

1. Are these phrases *correct* (by which I assume you mean grammatically correct)?

   Yes, they are grammatically correct. Just for fun, let's try reversing the construct to make it a statement, replacing the "which" with a concrete example.

   > Which team's game is it?  => It is the German team's game.
   >   Which team's game are you watching? => You are watching the German team's game.

   These are plenty grammatical, so it seems to follow that the general process of reversing the statement and adding a "which" to make it a question works just fine.
2. Are these phrases *appropriate* for their context? Perhaps, are they *natural*?

   This is, of course, a matter of opinion, but to my ears, neither sounds outright *unnatural*. The phrase "Which team's game is it?" sounds a little awkward, for sure (less so if you made it "Which team's game is *this*?"), but "Which team's game are you watching?" sounds perfectly fine. You would be perfectly understood using either construction, and likely no one would question you.

   The one comment I will make is that "Which team's game is it?" wouldn't work very well if you said it as the first sentence in a conversation, e.g. if you walked in the room, saw a game on the TV, and opened with that phrase. "It" refers usually to a predefined object, but since there has been no previous discussion identifying the game on TV, it may take a half-second to realize you are talking about the one on TV. However, it works fine in an exchange such as the following:

   > P1: *Entering the room* What are you up to?
   >   P2: *Watching the television* Just watching the game.
   >   P1: Oh? Which team's game is it?

   No problem there at all.

   That said, it would very likely sound more *natural* if you were to use one of the phrases supplied by @kiamlaluno ("Which teams are playing?") or @Hellion ("Who's playing?" This is by far the most natural sounding to my American English ears).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know which teams are playing the game, I would ask "Which teams are playing?"

"Which team's game is it?" and "Which team's game are you watching?" don't seem something a native speaker would say. There is also the chance the answer would similar to "It's the final of the [UEFA Champions League](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Champions_League)."

Comment: Even more succinctly, you could say "Who's playing?"  and reasonably expect the team names as the answer.

Comment: Or just: *Whose game is this?*

Comment: @tchrist Could not the answer to that question be "the final of the UEFA Champions League"?